# options validator input is false?

Tags: options, settings-api

I have a form that looks as such:

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
      <a href="#content" data-toggle="tab">content</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contentversion2" data-toggle="tab">content version 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="content">
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="url" name="aisis_core[index_more_posts]" placeholder="Url" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="contentversion2">
      content for this tab as well
    </div>
  </div><input type="hidden" name="option_page" value="aisis_options" /><input type=
  "hidden" name="action" value="update" /><input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name=
  "_wpnonce" value="0360d57793" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value=
  "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=aisis-core-options&amp;settings-updated=true" />
</form>
```

The problem is, when I hit submit, the following options validator function is then called, based on the registered settings:

```
public function option_validator($input){
    var_dump($input); exit;
    $option = get_option('aitisis_core');
    $option = $input;
    update_option('success_message', true);
    return $option;
}
```

The problem as you can see from the var dump is that the input is always null....no matter what I put into the url input.

I registered the setting as such:

```
public function settings(){
    register_setting(
        'aisis_options', 
        'aisis_options', 
        array(
            $this, 
            'option_validator'
        )
    );
}
```

any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of setup skeleton works for me to process the custom options page input :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Settings Skeleton
*/

if(!class_exists('MySettings')){    

    function call_my_settings() {
        return new MySettings();
    }

    if (is_admin()){
        add_action( 'init', 'call_my_settings' );
    }

    class MySettings{

        public function __construct(){
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add_menu'));
            add_action('admin_init', array(&$this,'settings') );
        }

        public function add_menu(){
            add_options_page(__('My Plugin Settings','myplugindomain'), 'My Plugin Settings', 'manage_options', __FILE__,  array(&$this,'options_page'));
        }   

        public function settings() {
            register_setting( 'my_settings', 'my_settings', array(&$this,'validate') );
        }

        public function validate($input) {
            // do validation
            $input['mytext']=esc_attr($input['mytext']);
            return $input;
        }

        public function options_page(){
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="icon32" id="icon-options-general"><br></div>
            <h2><?php _e('My plugin settings','myplugindomain'); ?></h2>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields('my_settings'); ?>
                <?php $settings = get_option('my_settings'); ?>
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" colspan="2">
                            <h3><?php _e('General settings','myplugindomain'); ?></h3>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php _e('My text','myplugindomain'); ?> </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" size="70" name="my_settings[mytext]" value="<?php echo $settings[mytext]; ?>" />
                             </td>
                     </tr>
                </table>
                <?php submit_button(); ?>
             </form>
         </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you the following options page:

[image: settings menu]

[image: settings]

How do you hook your `settings()` function ?

In the code example above the `settings()` functions is hooked into the `admin_init` action, i.e.

```
add_action('admin_init', array(&$this,'settings') );
```